# Trying to mock a class in PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to mock a class for a test in PHPUnit, but I am unable to call the mock. Here is the class that I'm testing:

```
class AssessmentController extends Controller
{
    static public function fredsTest()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => []]);
        // dd($client);
        dd($client->post('hello')->getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
class AssessmentControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFredsTest() : void
    {
        $this->mock(\GuzzleHttp\Client::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('post')
                ->andReturn(
                    new class() {
                        public function getReasonPhrase() : string
                        {
                            return 'OK';
                        }
                    }
                );
        });

        \App\Http\Controllers\AssessmentController::fredsTest();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting this test to print 'OK' and then exit, but instead, it encounters an error in the `\GuzzleHttp\Client` code because `\GuzzleHttp\Client` is not mocked. (If I uncomment the line `dd($client);`, it outputs info about the `\GuzzleHttp\Client` instead of a mock object. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: `dd()` helper stops execution. What happens if you use `dump($client->post('hello')->getReasonPhrase());`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new client class directly instead try getting it from the container like so:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
// ...
$config = ['headers' => []];
$client = App::make(Client::class, ['config' => $config]);
```

This should use your mocked class.

note:

If you're mocking http requests you should use the `Http::fake` functionality though.

```php
Http::fake([
    '*/foobar' => Http::response(
        body: '{"foo":"bar"}',
        status: 201,
        headers: ['content-type' => 'application/json']
    )
]);

$response = Http::post('https://website.com/foobar');

/**
 * array:1 [
 *     "foo" => "bar"
 * ]
 */
dd($response->json());
```

Comment: I will add: always try to use `app(...)` or `resolve(...)` helper instead of `App::make(...)`, because you have to know by memory the `App`'s namespace and can totally change in the future, and the community favors those helpers I mentioned, but this answer is correct